# Float div on right, then drop below on narrow screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the effect illustrated below:

[image]

on my site (http://new.freshsourdoughexpress.com/contact/), but I can't think of the correct HTML and CSS to get it to work. The only way I can get the map to float up on the right is to put the iframe before the text div, but then I can't have the map drop below the text when I shrink the width. I'm out of ideas currently so I'm hoping someone else can point out the obvious. Thanks!

**EDIT -** Sorry, I posted this as I was running out the door and didn't post enough info. I currently do have a responsive layout (WP Twenty Thirteen theme). If I set the text div to `float: left` and the map iframe to `float: right` the text div occupies 100% of the width and the map drops below. I'm trying not to set a width on the text div because I want it to be able to resize with the window. (I'm trying to keep the dimensions of the map the same and have the text resize to fit. Using a percentage width on the text would require me to do the same with the map, which I'm trying not to do.)

If I put the iframe first in my HTML then the map will stay up at the top (the first three frames of the GIF) without setting a width (either in px or %), but then I can't have the map drop below the text. To achieve the last frame I had to move the iframe back below the text.

So I'm wondering if it's at all possible to get what I'm after without defining a width for the text div. If there isn't I suppose I can live with the map resizing. I was trying to do it without it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/puA72/2/)

for the left block use

```
float:left;
width:50%;
```

because it is currently width:100% automatically, you need to separate content as 50% 50%

then for the container block you must clear the float by

```
 display:inline-block;
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a solution where I could keep my map from resizing. If not, I guess I can live with the map getting squashed. I added more details to my question.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to resort to setting both widths to 50% and have the map get a bit squashed. It's not the end of the world.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work: the left div width is not occupy the space freed by the right div that moved under.

Answer (score 3):

use @media queries, something like this

```
.rightcol { float: right; }
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   .rightcol { float: none; }
}
```

this will set the `.rightcol` on all devices with screen size 600px or lower `float: none` and keep it `float: right` for the rest. You can of course change the 600px to whatever number you please.

Comment: The problem is that the map won't float up beside the text -- it gets pushed down. I added more details to my question.

Comment: @EverythingTech96 Then you will need to make do with setting the width using %. The percentage will make the div have the same portion of the parent width. So if the screen size got smaller on tab or phone, it will also get smaller.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score -1):

Simply float both elements to the left. Control the width of elements with percentage widths: something like `width: 50%;`

Simple example:

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/jNqL6/2/)

**Update** - Fiddle with text - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/jNqL6/3/)

HTML

```
<div id="text"></div>
<iframe></iframe>
```

CSS

```
#text {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #CCC;
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
}
iframe {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #333;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: In this example neither of the `divs` gets resized when the window is resized. I don't think this is what the author wants to do.

Comment: Ok, now it completely answers the question. :)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details; I added some. I'm trying to make the layout responsive, so I don't want to set static dimensions.

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle - [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jNqL6/3/) . Isn't that something like you want to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, except that the text doesn't fill the width once the iframe drops below. It looks like what I was trying to accomplish isn't easily done. I'll just have to resort to splitting it 50-50 and then use a media query to drop it below and expand the width of the text div on small screens.

Answer (score -1):

*Please don't ask for the answer, ask how to do it from your current code.*

What you're trying to create is a **responsive layout**. You can achieve what you asked for by using *media queries* in your CSS. Example of usage:

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
    .sidebar {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

To achieve the desired result there are three different ways to go:

- Create your layout from scratch

  - [Build a basic responsive site with CSS](http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/build-basic-responsive-site-css-1132756)
  - [Build a Responsive, Mobile-Friendly Website from Scratch](http://www.sitepoint.com/series/build-a-responsive-mobile-friendly-website-from-scratch/)
  - [30 Useful Responsive Web Design Tutorials](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/)
  - [Building responsive layouts](http://www.slideshare.net/zomigi/building-responsive-layouts)
  - ...
- Use a grid system

  - [Responsive Grid System](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/)
  - [13 Best Responsive CSS Grid Systems for Your Web Designs](http://designinstruct.com/web-design/responsive-css-grid/)
  - [34 Responsive Grid System](http://34grid.com/)
  - [Responsive Grid System](http://responsive.gs/)
  - [Golden Grid System](http://goldengridsystem.com/)
  - ...
- Use a web tool

  - [Responsive Web CSS](http://www.responsivewebcss.com/)

You can choose which way to go. But if you had posted a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) or some piece of code, we would be able to help you a little bit better. ;)

Comment: I currently have a responsive layout (I should've said that in the question, my bad). I added more details as to what my problem is and what I've tried.

Answer (score -1):

Well, your content area div doesn't have a name so it inherets any near divs style, name it then give it a fixed with and float left then you will find the map floated automaitcally right

Comment: I'm trying to make a responsive layout. I added more details to my question, since they were lacking.