# Moving Image below text when in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position an image below a piece of text when in mobile view, but, in it's current state, it's overwriting the block of text.

**This is how it looks on desktop**:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**This is how it looks on mobile at the moment** (the image is covering the text):

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**How I want it to look**:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

The general concept it to get the image between the text and button. I have tried to 'display:block' - my thinking was that if it's classed as a separate element, it will just slide after the text automatically, but to no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://static.hsstatic.net/jquery-libs/static-1.1/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">hsjQuery = window['jQuery']</script>
    <link href="https://static.hsstatic.net/content_shared_assets/static-1.4049/css/public_common.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="//cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/-1/hub_generated/template_assets/1495141902003/hubspot_default/shared/responsive/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://content.littlefish.co.uk/hs-fs/hub/1907421/hub_generated/template_assets/1509367336144/custom/page/Inbound/inbound.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://content.littlefish.co.uk/hs-fs/hub/1907421/hub_generated/template_assets/1515754183680/Custom/page/Inbound/audit.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|Source+Sans+Pro:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/f1a0f2ac-0b00-438c-950f-841026767235.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   




<div class="results-wrapper-container clearfix">
<div id="starmanLow" class="starmanText section-hidden" style="display: block;">
<h2>Unsatisfactory user centricity (0-40)</h2>
<p>Put simply, your Service Desk is not performing to an acceptable level, and as a result you’re putting your organisation’s performance at risk (while paying for the privilege). From the time it takes to resolve user issues, to overall business alignment and the skill levels on offer, your Service Desk is way below the standards you need to take your business to the next level.</p>
<p>We would strongly urge you to look at alternative partners who will be far more focused on delivering a personalised approach that puts your users first and foremost. Speak with Littlefish to discover how you benefit from a designated group of accredited technicians who truly understand your business and the needs of your users – and build on that knowledge with each contact. Littlefish resolves over 70% of issues at first point of contact and has a 95% customer satisfaction rating, which means your users remain productive and you get to focus on strategic operational decisions rather than being dragged in to deal with day-to-day firefighting.</p>
<div class="formLink">Stop wasting money and talk to Littlefish</div>
</div>
<div id="starmanMedium" class="starmanText section-hidden">
<h2>Satisfactory user centricity (41-80)</h2>
<p>Unfortunately, quite good isn’t good enough. Your Service Desk has some capabilities but you’re missing out on a full, user-centric service. And when margins are tight and the competition fierce, all your suppliers should be pulling you forward to greater operational efficiency. Is your Service Desk proactively introducing you to the latest systems, better tools, and suggesting more streamlined ways of working? Do you have a designated team, who know your users by name and understand what is important to them?</p>
<p>As your business grows and new challenges appear, you need a Service Desk that is flexible and professional enough to grow with you. Look for a Service Desk that can boast 95% customer satisfaction with over 70% of issues resolved at first contact. Don’t settle for second best: find a partner who will give you an optimal service time and time again.</p>,
<div class="formLink">Boost your business performance with Littlefish</div>
</div>
<div id="starmanHigh" class="starmanText section-hidden">
<h2>Excellent user centricity (81-100)</h2>
<p>Congratulations, we don’t often see many other Service Desks rated as excellent. That’s because Littlefish sets an extremely high bar when it comes to IT excellence. Our <a href="https://www.littlefish.co.uk/careers" target="_blank">Littlefish Academy</a> is a structured training and development program that ensures all our staff have the latest skills to offer a world-class service. Our first line is a second line capability engineer, which is why we deliver 95% customer satisfaction and resolve over 70% of issues at first point of contact.</p>
<p>While your current provider is delivering what they promised, what about delivering <em>more</em> than promised? Littlefish go above and beyond expectations with a ‘shift left’ philosophy – growing knowledge about your users and finding ways to optimise their experience. It’s a personal approach from a designated team that solves issues your users didn’t even know were there.</p>
<p>In a fast-evolving industry, it pays to look at your options. Chat to us for an honest comparison with your current provider’s talent.</p>
<div class="formLink">Learn the true meaning of talent with Littlefish</div>
</div>
<div class="starmanImage"><img src="http://admin.contento.mobi/starman/stargraph?handle=littlefish&amp;scores=5.00,5.00,5.00,5.00,4.00,2.00,2.00,2.00,5.00,5.00&amp;desired=9.00,10.00,7.00,9.00,10.00,9.00,9.00,10.00,10.00,10.00"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can post here? Maybe a JSFiddle or something similar?

Comment: Or better: A stacksnippet with relevant CSS and HTML

Comment: Also what is your approach to responsiveness on site? For example, do you use bootstrap?

Comment: See my update showing a [mcve] in a snippet

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494931/float-div-on-right-then-drop-below-on-narrow-screen

Comment: _“but, in it's current state, it's overwriting the block of text”_ - that’s because the image is absolutely positioned, so remove that on mobile ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `starmanImage div` remains as `position: absolute` while in Mobile.
And your `starmanImage img` has a `transform: translateY(-50%)`.

The problem is fixed once you remove those for Mobile devices.

```
//inside @media for Mobile Devices
.starmanImage{
    position: relative;
}
.starmanImage img{
    transform: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As  @CBroe said, it happens because your image div container has absolute positioning. just need to disable it when at certain screen size

```css
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .starmanImage img{
    transform: none !important;
  }
  .starmanCurve, .starmanImage {
    position: relative !important;
    /* This is just some top padding */
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://static.hsstatic.net/jquery-libs/static-1.1/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">hsjQuery = window['jQuery']</script>
    <link href="https://static.hsstatic.net/content_shared_assets/static-1.4049/css/public_common.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="//cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/-1/hub_generated/template_assets/1495141902003/hubspot_default/shared/responsive/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://content.littlefish.co.uk/hs-fs/hub/1907421/hub_generated/template_assets/1509367336144/custom/page/Inbound/inbound.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://content.littlefish.co.uk/hs-fs/hub/1907421/hub_generated/template_assets/1515754183680/Custom/page/Inbound/audit.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|Source+Sans+Pro:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/f1a0f2ac-0b00-438c-950f-841026767235.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   




<div class="results-wrapper-container clearfix">
<div id="starmanLow" class="starmanText section-hidden" style="display: block;">
<h2>Unsatisfactory user centricity (0-40)</h2>
<p>Put simply, your Service Desk is not performing to an acceptable level, and as a result you’re putting your organisation’s performance at risk (while paying for the privilege). From the time it takes to resolve user issues, to overall business alignment and the skill levels on offer, your Service Desk is way below the standards you need to take your business to the next level.</p>
<p>We would strongly urge you to look at alternative partners who will be far more focused on delivering a personalised approach that puts your users first and foremost. Speak with Littlefish to discover how you benefit from a designated group of accredited technicians who truly understand your business and the needs of your users – and build on that knowledge with each contact. Littlefish resolves over 70% of issues at first point of contact and has a 95% customer satisfaction rating, which means your users remain productive and you get to focus on strategic operational decisions rather than being dragged in to deal with day-to-day firefighting.</p>
<div class="formLink">Stop wasting money and talk to Littlefish</div>
</div>
<div id="starmanMedium" class="starmanText section-hidden">
<h2>Satisfactory user centricity (41-80)</h2>
<p>Unfortunately, quite good isn’t good enough. Your Service Desk has some capabilities but you’re missing out on a full, user-centric service. And when margins are tight and the competition fierce, all your suppliers should be pulling you forward to greater operational efficiency. Is your Service Desk proactively introducing you to the latest systems, better tools, and suggesting more streamlined ways of working? Do you have a designated team, who know your users by name and understand what is important to them?</p>
<p>As your business grows and new challenges appear, you need a Service Desk that is flexible and professional enough to grow with you. Look for a Service Desk that can boast 95% customer satisfaction with over 70% of issues resolved at first contact. Don’t settle for second best: find a partner who will give you an optimal service time and time again.</p>,
<div class="formLink">Boost your business performance with Littlefish</div>
</div>
<div id="starmanHigh" class="starmanText section-hidden">
<h2>Excellent user centricity (81-100)</h2>
<p>Congratulations, we don’t often see many other Service Desks rated as excellent. That’s because Littlefish sets an extremely high bar when it comes to IT excellence. Our <a href="https://www.littlefish.co.uk/careers" target="_blank">Littlefish Academy</a> is a structured training and development program that ensures all our staff have the latest skills to offer a world-class service. Our first line is a second line capability engineer, which is why we deliver 95% customer satisfaction and resolve over 70% of issues at first point of contact.</p>
<p>While your current provider is delivering what they promised, what about delivering <em>more</em> than promised? Littlefish go above and beyond expectations with a ‘shift left’ philosophy – growing knowledge about your users and finding ways to optimise their experience. It’s a personal approach from a designated team that solves issues your users didn’t even know were there.</p>
<p>In a fast-evolving industry, it pays to look at your options. Chat to us for an honest comparison with your current provider’s talent.</p>
<div class="formLink">Learn the true meaning of talent with Littlefish</div>
</div>
<div class="starmanImage"><img src="https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></div>
</div>
```